# Master-Detail View Controller and CoreData

Tags: swift

As new to swift, I am trying to work with Master View Controller where I read a blog using JSON and store it in core data. All is good except that I don't understand how data gets deleted from core data upon right swipe and delete. I am sorry to ask such question and honestly it is embarrassing. I know for sure the following code deletes it but I cant find its implementation nor do I understand how it knows which entity to delete the data from.

```
 func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                *tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)*
            case .Update:
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
            case .Move:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            default:
                return
        }
    }
```

Please help me understand how does it work.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That code is just changing the cells in your `UITableView`, it's not deleting anything from CoreData.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why don't I see the deleted entry upon re-run? I also put self.tableView.reloadData() in viewDidAppear.

Comment: Are you saving your `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its deleting at: tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) function. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in that code that deletes anything from Core Data. That code calls methods on `UITableView`. It sometimes tells the table view to delete a row from the screen but it has no effect on Core Data.

You delete data from Core Data using `NSManagedObjectContext`' `deleteObject:` method.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. What confused me was I dont see the entry when I re-run the application and when I delete my app from my simulator all entries go away. Apologies if I am wondering away from the original question.